# how to create an empty zip archve by php

Tags: php

how to create an empty zip archve by php
some thing like
new -> zip archive

Answer (score 10):

I use this code to return a zip file from an array of files to be zipped, if the array is empty, than it returns an empty zip archive, hope it helps.

```
function zipFiles($files){
  // "UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==" is the base64 encoded content of an empty zip archive
  if(count($files) == 0){
    return base64_decode("UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="); 
  }
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  ... do your stuff
  foreach($files as $file){
    ... do your stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Seems that this is indeed the only way to create a truly empty ZIP file with PHP.

Answer (score 8):

You were pretty close:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('my-archive.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

// To actually save the archive you have to put some file/dir into it
$zip->addFromString('tmp', '');
$zip->close();
```

You can find out more on [PHP's manual pages](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php).

Comment: It seems that you have to add some file/directory to the archive to save it what makes a perfect sense cause what's the point of an empty archive?

Comment: This does not create an empty ZIP file, it just creates a ZIP file with one dummy entry with name 'tmp' which is an empty file.

Answer (score 5):

Creating the '.' directory seems to work for me:

```
$zip->addEmptyDir('.');
```

It appears in some applications when listing the files in the ZIP but not when extracting it.

Comment: This does not produce an empty ZIP file, instead it creates a ZIP file with one entry which is an empty directory. Utilities like `unzip` will be able to tell the difference.